# How to return some variable from model to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Actually, I have Site name and Site URL variables & I have query data variable also. I want to pass these all variables to controller  how ? please help. I have passed all the variable but data is not coming to controller.

Model Code:

```
$siteName   =   $CI->config->item('siteName');
$siteURL   = site_url();
 $data = $this->db->select('id, credit, firstName, lastName, email')

                    ->where('id', $iddss)

                           ->where('archived is NULL')

                                ->get('users')

                                    ->row_array();

                             return $data.$siteName.$siteURL;
```

Controller Code:

```
$result     =   $this->LowCredit_model->info($data['data']);
```

Answer (score 0):

> you can get **site_url()** & **config item** in controller too no need to retrun it  from model
>
> Model

```
return $this->db->select('id, credit, firstName, lastName, email')
            ->where('id', $iddss)
            ->where('archived is NULL')
            ->get('users')
            ->row_array();
```

> Controller

```
$result= array();
$result['siteName'] = $this->config->item('siteName');
$result['site_url'] = site_url();
$result['result_data'] =   $this->LowCredit_model->info($data['data']);
```

Comment: Hi Boominathan Elango , thanks for replaying . ok how to pass jsonSuccess code is like ------$result['result_data']  = $this->LowCredit_model->info($data['data']);

   jsonSuccess($result,$result['succ_code']);